# Batch renaming using shell script

Tags: bash, unix, shell, rename

I have a folder with files named as

```
input (1).txt
input (2).txt
input (3).txt
...
input (207).txt
```

How do I rename them to

```
input_1.in
input_2.in
input_3.in
...
input_207.in
```

I am trying this

```
for f in *.txt ; do mv $f `echo $f | sed -e 's/input\ (\(\d*\))\.txt/input_\1.in/'` ; done
```

But it gives me

```
mv: target `(100).txt' is not a directory
mv: target `(101).txt' is not a directory
mv: target `(102).txt' is not a directory
...
```

Where did I go wrong?

---

I have put in the quotes now, but I get this now

```
mv: `input (90).txt' and `input (90).txt' are the same file
```

It is somehow trying to rename the file to the same name. How is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because bash `for` split the element with space ' ' so you are commanding it to move '`input`' to '`(1)`'.

The way to solve this is to tell bash to split by new line using `IFS` variable.

Like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Then do your command.

However, I suggest you to use `find` to do this instead using `-exec` command.

For example:

```
find *.txt -exec mv "{}" `echo "{}" | sed -e 's/input\ (\([0-9]*\))\.txt/input_\1.in/'` \;
```

NOTE: I write this from memory and I did test this so let try and adjust it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still this `mv: 'input (90).txt' and 'input (90).txt' are the same file`

Comment: I don't think you can use '\d' (from what I rememeber), try using '[0-9]'.

Comment: @Lazer: in `sed` the escape `\d` introduces a decimal character representation `\d97` == "a"

Answer (score 3):

You're forgetting to quote your arguments.

```
... mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | ... )" ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

no need to call external commands

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
for file in *.txt
do
  newfile="${file//[)]/}"
  newfile="${file// [(]/_}"
  mv "$file" "${newfile%.txt}.in"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've already fixed, you need to quote the `$f` argument to `mv`.

As to your second problem, `sed` doesn't support `\d`. You could use `[0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.txt ; do mv "$f" `echo $f | sed -e 's/input\ (\(\d*\))\.txt/input_\1.in/'` ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
seq 1 207 | parallel -q mv 'input ({}).txt' input_{}.in
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ